# pollute array or json with woocommerce product details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to pollute an array or json in order to use in a custom form, so that it changes with the data.

However, i have some issues on getting the right data

with some searching i now have this working:
(php)

```
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');
$post = $_POST;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product','product_variation',
        'tax_query' => array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'fields' => 'ids'
    ),
    );


    $myneededdata = new WP_Query( $args );

    echo json_encode($myneededdata);
```

and this works, but i want other data

i want it to return a JSON or array containing all products, with following data per product
- product id
- categories
- price
- tags
- title

how should i start with this?
i found this, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
but not sure how to use it, or someone knows a good tutorial about this part?

thanks in advance for your advice
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

found it,

using

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
     // polute data here, eg with get_the_ID() and so on
}
```